# Should i use react js as a SPA framework or go for server side rendering ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am in a dilemma that for a project which is scalable to big extent, server-side rendering is an option example node with express (using ejs) and render full html pages or go for front end routing like react-router

I am totally going for react for front end but confused for highly scalable application , front end routing option is good option or not

Comment: This question is too broad. The right choice will depend on what kind of web app you're going to implement.

Comment: No issues with either approach, but keep in mind, pulling down a big JS file every time your page loads might make load times slow, and a SPA ensures your application only has to do that once.

Comment: @Adam Not the best argument lol. With a server side application, you'll  have smaller js files where it doesn't matter. Either way this question is wayyyy to broad and should be closed.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm What are your opinion in SEO perspective , would it be good with a SPA , because i have faced a similar problem with angular , where i faced rendering my content to the bots , then i had to use 3rd party a plugin ...?

Comment: I wouldn't know, not an SEO specialist. Unfortunately I don't have any advice in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

React can handle anything you give it. Instagram is build on react. A common practice is developers creating their server as a REST api that does not render any page. You can then create your front end with react and use react to make API calls to your server and render the correct pages based on your responses. Compared to templating engines like ejs, first of all `jade` is a better templating engine compared to `ejs` but they do not offer the flexibility that comes with a framework like react.